# AFNetworking Send JSON as a parameter for POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking

I gone several answers for the same question...but unable to figure out this issue..i am getting this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization
>   dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON
>   write'

My code is:

```
NSDictionary *loginDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:password.text,@"password",userName.text,@"userName",nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginDict                                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted                                                              error:&error];
if (jsonData) {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
}


 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:20];
 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[manager POST:baseUrlLogin parameters:jsonString
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Try only these settings `AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    
    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    
    
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer=requestSerializer;`

Comment: @iphonic: Thanks for ur response...i tried ..but same error

Comment: what the result u get from this loginDict

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : {
    password = xxxxxxx;
    userName = "customer@mailinator.com";
}

Comment: Using `AFJSONRequestSerializer` will say that the parameter will be transformed into JSON. So you just have to give the `NSDictionary` directly (It will call by itself the `NSJSONSerialization` stuff).

Comment: @Larme : thanks for ur suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

directly pass `loginDict` in your call and check

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
/*
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:20];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
 */
[manager POST:baseUrlLogin parameters: loginDict
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: but i need to pass parameter in json..there the problem started

Comment: ya logindict has dictionary format , you can direct pass that

Comment: hey thanks when i commented that ,it is working..but i didnt get the reason

Comment: @Uday.M - the reason are you mention the response type as on your code, ok if my answer is useful give the tick and upvote the answer it is useful in future